# onChangeText giving Error in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

I have following code

```js
   import React from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet,Text,View,SafeAreaView,ScrollView ,Image ,TextInput} from 'react-native';     
   import  Entypo  from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
   import { Neomorph } from 'react-native-neomorph-shadows';

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  state = {
    fname : "",
    sname : "",
  }
  
  return(  <SafeAreaView style={{ alignSelf: "stretch" }}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
              <Neomorph style={styles.neomorph} >
                <Text style={styles.input_title}>First Name</Text>
                  <Neomorph inner style={styles.input} >
                  <TextInput
                    style={{ borderColor: 'transparent', borderWidth: 1 ,width: "100%" ,borderRadius: 8,height: 50,paddingLeft: 10,fontSize: 18,fontWeight:"bold",color:"#ffffff"}}
                    onChangeText={(nextValue) => this.setState({fname: nextValue})}
                    value={this.state.fname}
                  />
                  </Neomorph>
              </Neomorph>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.card}>
              <Neomorph style={styles.neomorph} >
                <Text style={styles.input_title}>Second Name</Text>
                  <Neomorph inner style={styles.input} >
                  <TextInput
                    style={{ borderColor: 'transparent', borderWidth: 1 ,width: "100%" ,borderRadius: 8,height: 50,paddingLeft: 10,fontSize: 18,fontWeight:"bold",color:"#ffffff"}}
                    onChangeText={(nextValue) => this.setState({sname: nextValue})}
                    value={this.state.sname}
                  />
                  </Neomorph>
              </Neomorph>
            </View>
 </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

onChangeText i am getting the error like this

```js
TypeError: _this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({
          fname: nextValue
        })', '_this.setState' is undefined)
```

Can anyone help me how to sort out this problem
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a functional component so state is not supported there.

You can switch to a class based component like below

```
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    fname : "",
    sname : "",
  }
  
  render()
{
 //return jsx
}
}
```

Or use the useState hook like below

```
export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [fname,setfname] = React.useState("");
  
  return()
}
```

you can use setfname("value") to set the value.

Comment: thanks @GuruparanGiritharan but for this i need to call handlefname and handleSname function but i am trying to do it in the same line like inside TextInput is there anyway?

Comment: Use the first option of a class based component, then you will have access to state

Comment: but i have to use navigation how i can use it in class based component?

Comment: you can access navigation as 'this.props.navigation' it'll be passed as a prop :)